# Why does Exception proxy __str__ onto the args?

Tags: python, exception, python-internals

Why does printing an exception instance print the value of `exc.args` instead of representing `exc` directly? The docs call it a [convenience](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) but it's actually an **inconvenience** in practice.

Can't tell the difference between *args and a tuple:

```
>>> print(Exception(123, 456))
(123, 456)
>>> print(Exception((123, 456)))
(123, 456)
```

Can't reliably discern type:

```
>>> print(Exception('123'))
123
>>> print(Exception(123))
123
```

And the lovely "invisible" exception:

```
>>> print(Exception())

>>>
```

Which you'll inherit unless you specifically ask not to:

```
>>> class MyError(Exception):
...     """an error in MyLibrary"""
...     
>>> print(MyError())

>>>
```

This can be a real problem if you forget to log error instances specifically with `repr` - a default string representation in a log file has irreversibly lost information.

**What's the rationale for such strange implementation of `Exception.__str__`**?  Presumably if a user wanted to print `exc.args` then they should just print `exc.args`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`BaseException.__str__` could have been fixed in a backwards-incompatible manner with Python 3 to include at least the type of the exception, but perhaps no one noticed that it is a thing that should be fixed.

The current implementation dates back to PEP 0352 which provides rationale:

> No restriction is placed upon what may be passed in for `args` for backwards-compatibility reasons. In practice, though, only a single string argument should be used. This keeps the string representation of the exception to be a useful message about the exception that is human-readable; this is why the `__str__` method special-cases on length-1 `args` value. Including programmatic information (e.g., an error code number) should be stored as a separate attribute in a subclass.

Of course Python itself breaks this principle of useful human-readable messages in many cases - for example stringification of a `KeyError` is the key that was not found, which leads to debug messages like

```
An error occurred: 42
```

---

The reason why `str(e)` is essentially `str(e.args)` or `str(e.args[0])` was originally backwards-compatibility with Python 1.0. In **Python 1.0**, the syntax for raising an exception, such as `ValueError` would have been:

```
>>> raise ValueError, 'x must be positive'
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
ValueError: x must be positive
```

Python retained backwards-compatibility with 1.0 up to 2.7, so that you can run most Python 1.0 programs unchanged in **Python 2.7** (like you never would):

```
>>> raise ValueError, 'x must be positive'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: x must be positive
```

Likewise, in **Python 1.0** you would catch the `ValueError` with

```
>>> try:
...     raise ValueError, 'foo'
... except ValueError, e:
...     print 'Got ValueError', e
```

which worked unchanged in Python 2.7.

But the mechanism of how this worked internally had changed: In Python 1.0.1, `ValueError` was a *string* with value... `'ValueError'`

```
>>> ValueError, type(ValueError)
('ValueError', <type 'string'>)
```

There were no exception classes at all, and you could only `raise` a single argument, or a tuple, with a string as a discriminator:

```
>>> class MyCustomException: 
...     pass
...   
>>> raise MyCustomException, 'my custom exception'
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
TypeError: exceptions must be strings
```

It would also be possible to give a tuple as an argument:

```
>>> raise ValueError, ('invalid value for x', 42)
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
ValueError: ('invalid value for x', 42)
```

And if you catch this "exception" in **Python 1.0**, what you get in `e` is:

```
>>> try:
...     raise ValueError, ('invalid value for x', 42)
... except ValueError, e:
...     print e, type(e)
... 
('invalid value for x', 42) 42 <type 'tuple'>
```

A *tuple*!

Let's try the code in **Python 2.7**:

```
>>> try:
...     raise ValueError, ('invalid value for x', 42)
... except ValueError, e:
...     print e, e[1], type(e)
... 
('invalid value for x', 42) 42 <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>
```

The output looks identical, except for the type of the value; which was a `tuple` before and now an exception... Not only does the `Exception` delegate `__str__` to the `args` member, but it also supports indexing like a tuple does - and unpacking, iteration and so on:

**Python 2.7**

```
>>> a, b, c = ValueError(1, 2, 3)
>>> print a, b, c
1 2 3
```

All these hacks for the purpose of keeping backwards-compatibility.

The Python 2.7 behaviour comes from the `BaseException` class that was introduced in [PEP 0352](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/); PEP 0352 was originally implemented in Python 2.5.

---

In Python 3, the old syntax was removed - you could not raise exceptions with `raise discriminator, (arg, um, ents)`; and the `except` could only use the `Exception as e` syntax.

PEP 0352 discussed about dropping support for multiple arguments to `BaseException`:

> It was decided that it would be better to deprecate the `message` attribute in Python 2.6 (and remove it in Python 2.7 and Python 3.0) and consider a more long-term transition strategy in Python 3.0 to remove multiple-argument support in `BaseException` in preference of accepting only a single argument. Thus the introduction of message and the original deprecation of `args` has been retracted.

Seemingly this deprecation of `args` was forgotten, as it still does exist in Python 3.7 and is the *only* way to access the arguments given to many built-in exceptions. Likewise `__str__` no longer needs to delegate to the args, and could actually alias the `BaseException.__repr__` which gives nicer, unambiguous representation:

```
>>> BaseException.__str__(ValueError('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))
"('foo', 'bar', 'baz')"
>>> BaseException.__repr__(ValueError('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))
"ValueError('foo', 'bar', 'baz')"
```

but no one considered it.

---

P.S. The `repr` of an exception is useful - next time try printing your exception with `!r` format:

```
print(f'Oops, I got a {e!r}')
```

which results in

```
ZeroDivisionError('division by zero',)
```

being output.